# Using MVC4 DropDownList helper for deeply nested properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In my view I need to create a drop down list for a property that is not in the immediate view model, rather nested within two more levels of view models. It's arranged as so:

`patient -> (list)referrals -> (list)bookings.attendanceId`

How would I use the `DropDownListFor` helper in this case? The problem is not finding the `List<SelectListItem>` but pointing the helper to the scalar value the drop down selection should fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just an opinion, one of the main reason we use view models if to simplify the domain models to only what you explicitly need in the view. So my question to you is why is your view model so complex?

That being said the only way to accomplish what you want to do is to have your drop down list nested inside 2 for loops like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Referrals.Count; i++)
{
    @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Referrals[i].Bookings.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Referrals[i].Bookings[j].AttendanceId, Model.SomeSelectList)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point Marko, I have considered flattening all my complex view models, although there are a few instances when I require a lot of information, which is why I've essentially added navigation properties to some view models.

Comment: Doesn't the DropDownListFor method require a lambda expression for its first parameter?

Comment: @Lee Indeed it does it was an oversight on my part. Fixed now... thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Referrals .Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < Model.Referrals[i].Bookings.Count; j++)
  {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Referrals[i].Bookings[j].AttendanceId, Model.YourSelectList)
```